# Program uses outdated (not current) env variable value

Tags: java, windows, visual-c++, classpath, environment-variables

I've got a C++ program that internally uses java (via my C++ dll that wrapps the WebLogic jsmc.dll that internally uses jvm.dll).

When I set CLASSPATH before running my program, all JAR libraries are found and the program works properly.
When I do **not** set the CLASSPATH before running my program, the JARs are **not** found, which of course is expected.

Now, when I set the CLASSPATH before running my program, but **clear** this CLASSPATH environment variable inside the program code **before** loading my dll that uses java, a strange thing happens: all JARs are still found and the program works as if everything was OK. I have verified by several ways that the CLASSPATH is really deleted from the env variables (e.g. by using ProcessExplorer or by printing its value).

QUESTION:

Can you explain this behaviour to me? I'm **not** wondering why java ignores the CLASSPATH I set, but **how is it possible** that java sees the old CLASSPATH value, not the current one? I emphasize that it isn't possible for java to store the old CLASSPATH value somehow because java was not loaded at the the time the old value was available.

How can I make the java to respect the changes in the process env variables?

DETAILS:

The problem above is just a simplification I've made to explore my real problem. I'm trying to set the CLASSPATH from within the program and avoid to have it set externally. But the java uses the externally set CLASSPATH, not the one I set inside the program.

I read and set the env variables values using the Windows API (GetEnvironmentVariableA, SetEnvironmentVariableA). I have verified that the program process environment variables really change after setting them this way. I even printed the CLASSPATH value from the dll that uses java, before calling any java method. I checked using the ProcessMonitor that jvm.dll is really loaded **after** the CLASSPATH is deleted. I also tried to exclude the possibility that the CLASSPATH is read from the parent process. Now I'm pretty sure that at the time jvm.dll is being loaded, the CLASSPATH is already deleted from the process environment.

I have tried both a Visual C++ 2010 testing program and the HP LoadRunner C-compiler (mmdrv.exe) vuser script, with the same result. LoadRunner is the main reason why I need to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the CLASSPATH being used can only be coming from the parent process (e.g., the command shell) and not from, e.g., the default environment variable values stored in the registry?

Comment: I managed to get the code working from the Visual Studio. It was sufficient to mark "jmsc.dll" as lazily loaded (Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Delay Loaded Dlls = "jmsc.dll").

Unfortunately, the same code doesn't work the same way from the LoadRunner - even though the dll is loaded lazily, the loaded dll still uses the original CLASSPATH, not the modified one. :-((( Probably some quirks in the implementation of lr_load_dll().

Comment: One possible explanation is that the C runtime contained in or referenced by jmsc.dll might be making its own copy of the environment variables at startup.  I'm not sure how they would wind up in jvm.dll: perhaps it uses the same runtime, or perhaps jmsc.dll is explicitly passing the CLASSPATH to jvm.dll for some reason.  You'd need to look at it with a debugger to know for sure.

Comment: I've already tested this. 1)jvm.dll has to be assigned the classpath explicitly while creating the JVM instance, see answer of Peter Cetinski below and the following comments. 2)Someone suggested to me that MCVCRT.DLL keeps its own copy of the environment. So I changed SetEnvironmentVariableA() to _putenv(), with no effect. _putenv is implemented in msvcrt.

Comment: But perhaps your program is not using the same instance of the runtime as jsmc.dll?

Comment: I do not use java directly, only through the jmsc.dll. Jmsc.dll imports from jvm.dll only one function - JNI_CreateJavaVM() that creates the JVM. This JVM uses the old classpath. There is no other JVM instance. My application is a jmsc.dll client, and it tries to modify the classpath before the jmsc.dll is even loaded - in LR unsuccessfully, in VS with success. It modifies the classpath using SetEnvironmentVariableA(), or using _putenv().

Comment: Let me rephrase: but perhaps your program is not using the same instance of the C runtime as jsmc.dll?  Each instance might have its own copy of the environment block.  That is, your call to _putenv and jmsc.dll's call to _getenv might be to different runtime libraries, referencing different copies of the environment.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant instances of JVM. 

And yes, you're right: jmsc.dll uses msvcrt.dll, while my code was using msvcr100.dll. When I re-linked my code to use msvcrt.dll as well, everything began to work! :-)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by that the C-runtime somehow caches the environment variables. While I was trying to modify the CLASSPATH using the system function SetEnvironmentVariableA(), jmsc.dll read CLASSPATH from the C-runtime cache. The C-runtime tries to synchronize its cache with the real values in the process environment, but evidently not very successfully. It was necessary for me to replace the system call to SetEnvironmentVariableA() with the call to _putenv() from the C-runtime in order to change the CLASSPATH.

But there was another problem. There were various versions of C-runtime used by my code, each having its own environment cache. My VC code was linked against msvcr100.dll, while jmsc.dll (that instantiates the Java VM) uses msvcrt.dll. The solution was to link my code to msvcrt.dll too, so that my code sets CLASSPATH using _putenv() from the same C-runtime that jmsc.dll reads.

Thanks to *Harry Johnston* for the crucial hint, and *Peter Cetinski* for valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely upon the CLASSPATH environment variable when invoking a new JVM process  from C++.  The JNI interface provides a mechanism to specify the classpath of the JVM upon startup.

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html#28719

Comment: Good idea :). However, I'm not creating the JVM explicitly, so I cannot set the JavaVMInitArgs' parameters. I just use the jmsc.dll library (the Weblogic C-API for JMS) that creates its own JVM. If I undestand your link correctly, if I created a JVM using JNI_CreateJavaVM(), that would be a new instance of JVM, different from the one that the jmsc.dll creates.

Comment: You are right, it would be a different process.  I am sure that jmsc.dll is simply calling JNI_CreateJavaVM.

Comment: Well, I at least shall test what happens when creating a new JVM and clearing the classpath in runtime immediately before it.

Comment: Result: The JNI_CreateJavaVM() searches for class-files in the current directory only, unless its classpath is set explicitly via the JavaVMOption structure (see the link above). I.e. the CLASSPATH environment variable has no influence.